# May i get gist without all history of changes?

Tags: api, github, gist

This is request to get single gist
GET /gists/:id
http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist

And it work.
But there is a problem: every time I get all history of gist changes. And after couple of days there are BIG amount of data to transfer. Is there any way to get only last state, without history?

Answer (score 1):

No API for this.

But if the gist only has one file, you can just make a GET request for `https://gist.github.com/user/gist-id/raw`.

If one gist has multiple files, you can just make GET requests for `https://gist.github.com/user/gist-id/raw/filename`.